# Rails: Some seeds don't appear to be saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, seed, ruby-on-rails-3.1

It appears some of my seeds are not saving. For starters, I will show a console session so you can see that the 'instructor_id' is indeed being set in the console, but not when I seed.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :015 > c = Course.find 2
  Course Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "courses".* FROM "courses" WHERE "courses"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
 => #<Course id: 2, name: "Microcomputers II Lab", course_code: "CE-420L", instructor_id: nil, school_id: nil, created_at: "2011-06-04 19:40:32", updated_at: "2011-06-04 19:40:32"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :016 > c.instructor = Instructor.first
  Instructor Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "instructors".* FROM "instructors" LIMIT 1
 => #<Instructor id: 1, name: "Instructor Name", created_at: "2011-06-04 19:40:32", updated_at: "2011-06-04 19:40:32"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :017 > c
 => #<Course id: 2, name: "Microcomputers II Lab", course_code: "CE-420L", instructor_id: 1, school_id: nil, created_at: "2011-06-04 19:40:32", updated_at: "2011-06-04 19:40:32">
```

From looking at the console, you can see that when I call c.instructor = Instructor.first, it is correctly setting my instructor_id.

Now, in the seeds file I have variables. (This is just a snippet)

```
### Instructors ###
puts "Creating Instructors"
instructor_1  = Instructor.find_or_create_by_name("Instructor Name")

### Courses ###
puts "Creating Courses"
ce420L   = Course.find_or_create_by_name("Microcomputers II Lab",                    :course_code => "CE-420L")

### Add the Instructor to the Course ###
puts "Adding an Instructor to the Courses"
ce420L.instructor  = instructor_1
```

But when I run the seeds using 'rake db:seed', it is correctly creating all of my models, and most of my relationships. But it is not setting the instructor properly.

Thoughts?

EDIT:

Just tried:

```
ce420   = Course.find_or_initialize_by_name("Microcomputers II")
ce420.instructor_id  = instructor_1.id
ce420.save!
```

And it did not save my instructor.

Here are my models.

```
class Instructor < ActiveRecord::Base
  ### ASSOCIATIONS ###
  has_many :courses
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :instructor
end
```

Comment: Wait... is the issue that the instructor itself isn't being created? Or that the course is not being tied to the instructor?

Comment: The course is not being tied to the instructor.

Comment: Not the way I was doing it anyway, I wanted to create lots of instructors, create lots of courses, then assign all of those instructors to the courses. Each in a separate area in the seeds file. But apparently I have to do it all at once, which will be a massive pain.

Comment: you don't have to do it all at once. It's just a bit faster because the system doesn't have to validate/save Course twice. You can separate out the work though if it's easier to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much faster to do this:

```
### Courses ###
puts "Creating Courses belonging to Instructor 1"
ce420L   = Course.find_or_initialize_by_name("Microcomputers II Lab")                    :course_code => "CE-420L")
ce420L.instructor_id = instructor_1.id
ce420L.save
```

Note the following:

1. You had an errant comma after your `find_or_create` on ce420L.
2. Doing the assignment together with the course creation prevents the system from validating and saving ce420L twice.
3. You can try assigning the specific ID as I did, i.e. ce420L.instructor_id = ...

If this doesn't work, check your Instructor Model to ensure you don't have any callbacks getting in the way.

Comment: The errant comma was a mishap when editing my post. I'll do some checks, thanks.

Comment: Okay, that did work for me... I've still no clue why it wasn't working earlier... and now because I have a lot of seeding, my seeds file is going to look terrible.

Comment: @ardavis - if you want to preserve your seeds file, try deconstructing parts of what I suggested above until you get that separation you're looking for. You can assign the instructor separately, just try it!

Answer (score 3):

Did you run...

```
ce420L.save!
```

... after assigning the instructor?

Comment: I'm seeding a lot of courses, and many of them are named. How comes this won't work:

puts "Saving the courses"
Course.all.each do |course|
  course.save!
end

Is there a way to save all unsaved models?

I'm confused why it saves in the console, but not the seeds.

Comment: `Course.all.each` only retrieves the **already saved courses in the database**.